# How to have both my Vue.js webpack project and Firebase functions, run on the same port?

Tags: firebase, webpack, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, vue-loader

**Vue.js & Firebase**

I have this interesting situation where I have installed a `vue.js webpack` project though the `vue cli`, as well as a Firebase project with hosting and functions (a node express app).

**Port 8080 & 5000**

Now, if I run the Vue project with `npm run dev`, then the Vue project builds and runs on `localhost:8080`. Which is fine. It has hot reloading, it runs and does what it needs to be doing.

But, I want the Vue project to use Firebase's functions for its back-end API calls. Sadly, Firebase runs on `localhost:5000`.

**Same-origin policy violation**

Of course, I could use JSONP, but that's just silly as there would be no reason for it other than developer convenience due to this port mismatch.

When I deploy the project, it builds the Vue projects, pushes the /dist folder to Firebase and both the Vue front-end and the Firebase functions back-end (express) run on the same domain on port 80. So, in production it's fine. But I want to use the development environment of the Vue project while developing.

Any ideas on how to overcome this issue? **Is there a way to have either Vue run on :5000 or Firebase functions on :8080?** Other suggestions maybe?

Comment: As a workaround, I use https://github.com/expressjs/cors in the development environment to allow for CORS from localhost:8080.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `firebase serve --help`, the output is this:

```
Usage: serve [options]

start a local server for your static assets

Options:

-p, --port <port>   the port on which to listen (default: 5000) (default: 5000)
-o, --host <host>   the host on which to listen (default: localhost) (default: localhost)
--only <targets>    only serve specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
--except <targets>  serve all except specified targets (valid targets are: functions, hosting)
-h, --help          output usage information
```

Note that you can use `--host` and `--port` to change where it serves.

Comment: Sadly, both Vue and Firebase try to avoid conflicting ports. Once one of these runs, the other avoids port 8080 and goes to 8081, or 8082, or even 8083.

Comment: Well, yeah, you haven't have two processes listing to the same port.  The OS won't allow that.

Comment: so it appears. Kind of irritating I have to find a work around now.

Comment: You could configure the host and port in your code, then use cors on both ends to make sure you can cross between them.

Answer (score 2):

Add CORS support to your express app to get rid of the same origin policy violation

Here is some sample code (not my creation)

Make sure you add CORS_URLS environment variable so that you are accepting * in production

```
let express = require('express')
let cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
const corsUrls = (process.env.CORS_URLS || '*').split(',');

  app.use(cors({
    origin: (origin, cb) => cb(null, corsUrls.includes('*') || corsUrls.includes(origin)),
    credentials: true,
  }))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vue cli 3, you can setup a proxy to allow calls to be ported to the firebase port.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

```
If you want to have more control over the proxy behavior, you can also use an object with path: options pairs. Consult http-proxy-middleware

for full options:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: '<url>',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      '/foo': {
        target: '<other_url>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```